# Estimating variability of unseen factor

Tags: probability, estimation, binomial-distribution, variance

I'm looking at binomial data where I believe that the probability of the outcome is the product of two independent factors. If you think of it as a two step decision,

1. At the first step, there is a certain probability $p$ that you will have a success, and $1-p$ that you will have a failure. If you have a failure at this step, there is no further opportunity for success.
2. Then, at the second step, there is a certain probability $q$ of success.

So, the overall probability of success is $p\times q$. I'm assuming, for now, that $p$ and $q$ vary independently across individuals. Both $p$ and $q$ have some variance across individuals, but not necessarily the same one.

Due to the nature of the data, I can estimate the variance of $q$, and the variance of $p\times q$. From this, I would like to estimate the variance of $p$. I just can't wrap my mind around how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing for independent $X$, $Y$, we know $E[X]$, $E[XY]$, $var(X)$, $var(XY)$.  Thus we know $E[Y] = E[XY]/E[X]$, $E[X^2]=var(X) - E[X]^2$ and $E[(XY)^2]=var[XY]-E[XY]^2$.

Since $E[(XY)^2] = E[X^2 Y^2] = E[X^2] E[Y^2]$ for independent $X$, $Y$, we have $E[Y^2] = E[(XY)^2]/E[X^2]$.

To summarize,

$$var(Y) = \frac{var(XY) + E[XY]^2}{var(X) + E[X]^2}- \left(\frac{E[XY]}{E[X]}\right)^2.$$